# Get more than one value with cookies?

Tags: cookies

I made 3 cookies using ***https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie*** library, one is getting user's name, other the user's last name and the user's email.

Do you know how can I merge those three values in just one cookie?

Thanks for your help.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'


function setEmailCookie() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var email_value = $(".email_cookie").val()
         Cookies.set('customer-email', email_value);
    })
}

function setNameCookie() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var name_value = $(".name_cookie").val()
         Cookies.set('customer-name', name_value);
    })
}

function setSurnameCookie() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var surname_value = $(".surname_cookie").val()
         Cookies.set('customer-surname', surname_value);
    })
}

function setZendeskCookie() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setEmailCookie();
        setNameCookie();
        setSurnameCookie();
    })
}

export default setZendeskCookie;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are not meant to hold a large amount of data.
If you really must use one cookie, you can store object as a string in a cookie such as

```
var customerInfo = {
    email: email_value,
    name: name_value,
    surname: surname_value,
};

Cookies.set("customer-info", JSON.stringify(customerInfo);
```

Then you would have to deserialize as such:

```
var customerInfo = JSON.parse(Cookies.get("customer-info"));
```